# Fill up according to correlation

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have the following two worksheets.
Worksheet1 (ws1) with the correlation between numbers.

```
A   B
0   5
1   7
2   8
3   12
4   16
```

And worksheet2 (ws2) with the gaps that need to be filled in.

```
A   B
3   ?
1   ?
0   ?
2   ?
2   ?
3   ?
```

When ws2-A = ws1-A, then I need ws2-B = ws1-B. How do I do this as a whole correlation without typing all by myself like dozens of IF(ws2-A1=ws1-A1,ws1-B1,IF(ws2-A1=ws1-A2,ws1-B2,IF(.... and so on.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped aswell. VLOOKUP() is also a ncie function to handle this kind of tasks!

Comment: INDEX/MATCH is faster and more versatile. With VLOOKUP, the lookup column has to be to the left of the desired retrieved data; with INDEX/MATCH it can be on either side.

Comment: INDEX/MATCH is faster and more versatile. With VLOOKUP, the lookup column has to be to the left of the desired retrieved data; with INDEX/MATCH it can be on either side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Follow this method to fix the issue.*

[image]

---

[image]

- Enter this formula in `Sheet 2` Cell `C1`, fill down.

`=INDEX(Sheet1!U$2:U$6,MATCH(B1,Sheet1!T$2:T$6,0))`

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you @Bfzn,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

All you need (with how your data is set up) is `INDEX`:

Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,A1+1)
```

If you have headers on sheet1 you might want to `+2`