# fill data automatically in excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

i have an excel file that have a list of EmployeeID and empty EmployeeFirst and Last name

and i have another file that have the employee id, first name and last name
for example :

First File

```
EmployeeID    
5    
2    
5    
11    
12    
2    
3    
5
```

Second File

```
EmplyeeID   EmplyeeFirstName  EmployeeLastName    
1           Will              Smith    
2           Michael           Jackson    
3           Bob               Marley    
4           Barack            Obama    
5           Donald            Trump
```

How can i fill the first and last name in the first file in the correct places according to the EmployeeID automatically ?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Of course. VLOOKUP() function will help.

Comment: @Akina i know nothing about vba, can you right an example script please

Comment: It is not VBA. It is worksheet function.

Comment: @Akina oh i see, sorry, thank you, i will try it and let you know

Comment: @MJ,, just check [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1478332/fill-up-according-to-correlation/1478337#1478337) help you to fix the issue.

Comment: @Akina please check the file https://www.mediafire.com/file/j4iuw79rt7rgvoi/backup.xlsx/file

Comment: VLOOKUP is not helpful? I can use VLOOKUP and get the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNmJ0.png

Comment: @Lee It will give #N/A in some cells. I'm not sure it is safe for OP.

Comment: @Lee what's the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume files are referred to as File1.XLSX and File2.XLSX respectively.
Data is posessed on a worksheet named Sheet1 in both files starting from A1 cell.

- Open both files.
- Activate File1
- Select B1.
- Enter the formula:

  ```
  =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A1,[file2.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$C,COLUMN(),FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP($A1,[file2.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$C,COLUMN(),FALSE))
  ```
- Select B1.
- Drag it right till C2.
- Drad selection down till B9:C9.

That's all.

PS. If you need the final data to be static, then use Copy - Paste special - Values.

---

> @Akina please check the file mediafire.com/file/j4iuw79rt7rgvoi/backup.xlsx/file – M J 10 mins ago

Use the formula:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B2,Feuil2!$A:$C,COLUMN()-1,FALSE)), "", VLOOKUP($B2,Feuil2!$A:$C,COLUMN()-1,FALSE))
```

Enter it into worksheet Feuil1, cell C2. Enter it into D2. The rest cells will be filled automatically.

---

> i'm getting error about '=1+1

If there are some problems then try to enter formula via VBA:

- open VBA editor (Alt-F11)
- open Immediate window (Ctrl-G)
- enter first two commands directly like on my screenshot (check for quotes, do not forget to press Enter after each separate command)
- close VBA editor

Then check where worksheet cell function differs, and remember this difference for future.

Comment: Are you sure about that? because nothing happen, also is it better to use one file but two sheets? because that's what i did, but i tried your function with two files, didn't worked

Comment: please check the link i posted

Comment: if you can do it in the file, i'm not familiar with excel

Comment: @MJ You tell "2 files" whereas you have 2 sheets in one file. You do not tell that you have "smart table".

Comment: @MJ,, I'm really surprised ,, that you have written ,, *i'm not familiar with excel*,,, !! We are here to suggest & support but not doing job like home work!!

Comment: @RajeshS where you see that i'm asking to do the job for me? the link is just to understand the file that i have, like smart table... i don't know about those things

Comment: @Akina so i need to enter that code in C2 Feuil1 and also D2 Feuil1 ? because it didn't worked, only the code showing in C2 and D2, is that part  `, """",` correct?

Comment: @MJ Oops. Misprint. Only 2 d-quotes needed. Edited. They were doubled because I have national Excel - so I insert the formula using VBA `cells(2,3).Formula=` technique, which needs doubling in string literals.

Comment: @Akina did you tried the function? there's an error

Comment: @Akina i'm getting error about '=1+1 ...

Comment: @MJ,, I said about this ,,*if you can do it in the file, i'm not familiar with excel*,,, your comment above!

Comment: @MJ I have tested using your file. https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZKqu.png *i'm getting error about '=1+1* Check yourself for misprint. Check if your Excel version uses semicolon as formula parameter separator instead of comma (edit formula in that case).

Comment: @Akina i'm using excel 2019, i'm installing the english lanuage to show you the error, please bear with me

Comment: @Akina check https://i.imgur.com/bNHtk4V.png

Comment: @MJ Try to build this formula step-by-step using formula building (`fx` knob). Or try to enter formula via VBA: open VBA editor (Alt-F11), Open Immediate window (Ctrl-G), enter first two commands directly like on my screenshot (check for quotes, do not forget to press Enter after each separate command). Then check where worksheet cell function differs, and remember this difference for future.

Comment: @Akina i replaced all comma with semicolon as you said before, and it worked, thank you, last question, if i open this file in excel 2013, it will work? or i need to change back the function from semicolon to comma ?

Comment: @MJ *if i open this file in excel 2013, it will work?* No constructions not safe for Excel 2013 (and ever Excel 2007) were used. Must work...

Comment: @RajeshS be like Akina, Helpful

Comment: @Akina Alright, thank you, appreciate your help